# Stubbed method can't be found in rspec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec3

In my controller I have code like...

```
def apply
  ...do some validation stuff
  jobapp = JobApplication.new
  jobapp.apply_for_job(params, job)
end
```

In my test I want to make sure that after all the validation passes, that the apply_for_job method was called so I have the following test.

```
describe 'apply' do
    before(:each) do
      @file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures/files/test-resume.txt'), 'plain/text')
      allow_any_instance_of(JobApplication).to receive(:apply_for_job).and_return(true)
    end

    it 'assuming all validation passes, it calls the jobapplication apply_for_job method' do
      post :apply, file: @file, job_id: 1, format: :json
      expect_any_instance_of(JobApplication).to receive(:apply_for_job)
    end
end
```

When I run my test I get this error.

```
Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
Exactly one instance should have received the following message(s) but didn't: apply_for_job
```

Any ideas why?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`expect_any_instance` [sets the expectation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance#use-<code>expect-any-instance-of</code>-to-set-a-message-expectation-on-any-instance) at the time that line of code is executed. It does not verify an expectation on a [spy](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/basics/spies).

You are setting the expectation *after* your code under test has run. Move the expectation definition up one line:

```
 expect_any_instance_of(JobApplication).to receive(:apply_for_job)

 post :apply, file: @file, job_id: 1, format: :json
```